# Game over when reaching the bottom of the screen

Tags: pygame

The point of this game is to shoot enemy ships. I need to add a loss condition. It consists in the fact that after the enemies have reached the bottom of the screen, the game should stop, and the bullets and enemies will disappear from the screen. In a couple of seconds everything should resume again
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GZ5H.png)

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.sprite import Group

pygame.init()

# screen parameters
height, width = 800, 650 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))


# player
class Ship:
    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(300, 710, 80, 80)#creating a players square
        self.color = (255, 255, 255)

        self.move_left = False
        self.move_right = False

    def move(self):
        if self.move_left == True: #the True/False assignment condition occurs in the main game loop
            self.rect.centerx -= 1
        elif self.move_right == True:
            self.rect.centerx += 1
        if self.rect.right >= 650:
            self.rect.right = 650
        elif self.rect.left <= 0:
            self.rect.left = 0

    def output_s(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)


# bullets
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, screen, my_ship):
        super(Bullet, self).__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 100, 10) #creating a bullet 
        self.speed = 5
        self.rect.centerx = my_ship.rect.centerx #bullet spawn coordinates
        self.rect.top = my_ship.rect.top
        self.y = self.rect.y

    def update(self):
        """bullet movement"""
        self.y -= self.speed
        self.rect.y = self.y

    def draw_bullet(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (255, 255, 255), self.rect)


# enemies
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, screen):
        super(Enemy, self).__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 70, 70)
        self.rect.top = self.screen_rect.top
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

    def output_e(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (255, 255, 255), self.rect)

    def update(self):
        self.y += 0.1
        self.rect.y = self.y


# objects of classes and groups
my_ship = Ship(screen)
bullets = Group()
enemys = Group()

# creating a row of enemies 
def create_enemy(screen, enemys, width):
    enemy_width = Enemy(screen).rect.width
    e_numbers = (width - 50) // enemy_width #numbers of enemies in row
    for i in range(e_numbers):
        enemy = Enemy(screen)
        enemy.x = 25 + (enemy_width + 25) * i #distance of ships from each other
        enemy.rect.x = enemy.x
        enemys.add(enemy) #adding an enemy to in row-group


# bullets movement and bullets collision with enemies
def update_bullets(bullets, enemys):
    bullets.update()
    collision = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bullets, enemys, True, True) #collision between enemy and bullet
    for bullet in bullets.copy():
        if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
            bullets.remove(bullet) #remove a bullet that reaches the bottom of the screen


# rendering of bullets, player and enemies on the screen
def screen_update(screen, enemys, bullets):
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for enemy in enemys:
        enemy.output_e()
    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw_bullet()
    my_ship.output_s()
    my_ship.move() #calling a move method
    pygame.display.flip()

#GAME LOOP
def main():
    create_enemy(screen, enemys, width)  #rendering a first row of enemies
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    my_ship.move_left = True
                elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    my_ship.move_right = True
                # shooting, creating a new bullet when pressing SPACE
                elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:

                    new_bullet = Bullet(screen, my_ship)
                    bullets.add(new_bullet)

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    my_ship.move_left = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    my_ship.move_right = False


        #creating rows following each other
        last_enemy = enemys.sprites()[-1] #tracking the last row that appeared
        if enemys and last_enemy.rect.y >= 100:
            create_enemy(screen, enemys, width)

        enemys.update() #enemies movement
        update_bullets(bullets, enemys) #bullets movement and bullets collision
        screen_update(screen, enemys, bullets) #rendering objects on screen and screen update


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I tried to make such a condition. But the first row was always tracked and the game ended, even if it was completely destroyed.

```
for enemy in enemys.sprites():
    if enemy.rect.bottom >= screen.get_rect().bottom:
        #game_over
```

Conditions of game_over works even when none of the rows have reached the end of the screen

Comment: On the right  side of the screen, there are some enemies out of bounds. You can't see them on the screen, but they still move down and collide with the bottom of the screen. Replace `for i in range(e_numbers):` with `for i in range(e_numbers - 1):` in `create_enemy`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason your code does not work is because there are enemies that exist outside of the window. This is why it appears your code triggers when no enemies exist-you just cannot see them. By changing the `for i in range(e_numbers)` to `for i in range(e_numbers - 1)` as the comment on the original post says, this problem is fixed. Below is the fixed code that pauses the game for two seconds after an enemy reaches the bottom and displays a message to the user.

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.sprite import Group

pygame.init()

# screen parameters
height, width = 800, 650 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))


# player
class Ship:
    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(300, 710, 80, 80)#creating a players square
        self.color = (255, 255, 255)

        self.move_left = False
        self.move_right = False

    def move(self):
        if self.move_left == True: #the True/False assignment condition occurs in the main game loop
            self.rect.centerx -= 1
        elif self.move_right == True:
            self.rect.centerx += 1
        if self.rect.right >= 650:
            self.rect.right = 650
        elif self.rect.left <= 0:
            self.rect.left = 0

    def output_s(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)


# bullets
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, screen, my_ship):
        super(Bullet, self).__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 100, 10) #creating a bullet 
        self.speed = 5
        self.rect.centerx = my_ship.rect.centerx #bullet spawn coordinates
        self.rect.top = my_ship.rect.top
        self.y = self.rect.y

    def update(self):
        """bullet movement"""
        self.y -= self.speed
        self.rect.y = self.y

    def draw_bullet(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (255, 255, 255), self.rect)


# enemies
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, screen):
        super(Enemy, self).__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 70, 70)
        self.rect.top = self.screen_rect.top
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

    def output_e(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (255, 255, 255), self.rect)

    def update(self):
        """Update enemy position and check if it has passed the bottom of the screen.

        Returns:
            bool: True if enemy is past the bottom of the screen, False if it is still valid.
        """
        self.y += 0.1
        self.rect.y = self.y
        if self.y > pygame.display.get_surface().get_height():
            return True
        return False

# objects of classes and groups
my_ship = Ship(screen)
bullets = Group()
enemys = Group()

# creating a row of enemies 
def create_enemy(screen, enemys, width):
    enemy_width = Enemy(screen).rect.width
    e_numbers = (width - 50) // enemy_width #numbers of enemies in row
    for i in range(e_numbers - 1):
        enemy = Enemy(screen)
        enemy.x = 25 + (enemy_width + 25) * i #distance of ships from each other
        enemy.rect.x = enemy.x
        enemys.add(enemy) #adding an enemy to in row-group


# bullets movement and bullets collision with enemies
def update_bullets(bullets, enemys:Group):
    bullets.update()
    collision = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bullets, enemys, True, True) #collision between enemy and bullet
    for intersection in collision:
        enemys.remove(collision.get(intersection))
    for bullet in bullets:
        if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
            bullets.remove(bullet) #remove a bullet that reaches the bottom of the screen


# rendering of bullets, player and enemies on the screen
def screen_update(screen, enemys, bullets):
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for enemy in enemys:
        enemy.output_e()
    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw_bullet()
    my_ship.output_s()
    my_ship.move() #calling a move method
    pygame.display.flip()

def pause():
    frame = 0
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    #show game over message (or whatever else you want here!)
    game_over = pygame.font.Font(pygame.font.get_default_font(), 50).render('GAME OVER!', False, (250, 20, 20), (20, 20, 20))
    pygame.display.get_surface().blit(game_over, (pygame.display.get_surface().get_width() / 2 - game_over.get_width() / 2, pygame.display.get_surface().get_height() / 2 - game_over.get_height() / 2))
    pygame.display.flip()

    #wait for two seconds
    while frame < 60:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
        frame += 1
        clock.tick(30)

#GAME LOOP
def main():
    global enemys
    reset = False

    while True:
            #reset groups
            bullets = Group()
            enemys = Group()
            create_enemy(screen, enemys, width)  #rendering a first row of enemies

            while not reset:
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        sys.exit()
                    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                            my_ship.move_left = True
                        elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                            my_ship.move_right = True
                        # shooting, creating a new bullet when pressing SPACE
                        elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:

                            new_bullet = Bullet(screen, my_ship)
                            bullets.add(new_bullet)

                    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                            my_ship.move_left = False
                        elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                            my_ship.move_right = False


                #creating rows following each other
                last_enemy = enemys.sprites()[-1] #tracking the last row that appeared
                if enemys and last_enemy.rect.y >= 100:
                    create_enemy(screen, enemys, width)

                update_bullets(bullets, enemys) #bullets movement and bullets collision
                for enemy in enemys:
                    if enemy.update(): #enemies movement
                        reset = True
                        continue
                screen_update(screen, enemys, bullets) #rendering objects on screen and screen update

            pause()
            reset = False       #game is no longer being reset


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Hopefully this helps, and let me know if you have any questions about it!